# Get git log range of remote branch

Tags: git, git-log

Getting the logs within a specified tag range works as expected:

```
git log v1..v2 --oneline
```

However, I want the tag range logs of `origin/master`. When I provide the tag range and remote/branch arguments I do not get as expected.

```
git log origin/master v1..v2 --oneline
```

The output is the same as if `v2` is not supplied at all. Indeed, when `v2` is removed, the output is from `v1` to `HEAD` of `origin/master`.

How can I make this command respect the tag range argument?

Git version 2.9.0

Comment: A Git tag is associated with a certain commit.  Are you sure that these commits exist in the remote tracking branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that this:

> ```
> git log origin/master v1..v2 --oneline
> ```

does not mean what you think it means.

[The gitrevisions syntax](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) `v1..v2` is short for `v2 ^v1`.  When you combine this with `origin/master`, you are giving Git all three selectors:

- include any commit *reachable from* tag `v2`;
- include any commit *reachable from* remote-tracking branch name `origin/master`;
- but *exclude* (from the whole list) any and all such commits that are *reachable from* the tag `v1`.

Suppose that you have this graph:

```
             o--o--o   <-- br1
            /
...--o--A--B--o        <-- br2
         \
          o--o--o      <-- br3
```

where each round `o` represents a commit.  The *names* `br1`, `br2`, and `br3` each *point to* one specific commit, which is the tip commit of each branch.

It's the actual commits themselves that point back to their previous commits.  I've given two particular commits `A` and `B` one-letter names here: these commits are extra-interesting, because commit `B` is on *both* branches `br1` and `br2`, and commit `A` is on *all three* branches.  This is because there are two commits "after" `B` that both point back to `B`.  Commit `B` is the *merge base* of branches `br1` and `br2`, so it's on both branches.  Likewise, `B` points back to `A`, but so does a commit on branch `br3`: commit `A` is the merge base of `br3` and `br2` (and also the merge base of `br3` and commit `B`).  So `A` is on both branches `br2` and `br3`, and since `B` is on `br1`, `A` is necessarily also on `br1`.

The idea of following commits back (leftward in this graph) to their *parent* commits is how Git determines this *reachability*.

Think of `v1` and `v2` as labels for specific commits, just like branch names, because that's how Git makes them work.  Tag names and branch names are both just names for one specific commit.  The difference is that a tag name is global—your tag `v2` should match everyone else's `v2`—and that tag names are *not supposed to move*.  A branch name like `br2` *automatically moves* when we add a new commit to the branch.  A tag name doesn't.

Let's draw another graph, this time with a `v1` and `v2` in it.  I don't have your repository so this is not an accurate graph of *your* repository, but it will, I hope, illustrate the principle:

```
...--o--v1--A--B--C--D--v2    <-- branch
         \            \
          F--G--H--I---J--K   <-- origin/master
```

When we say `^v1` we are asking Git to "paint commit v1, and all earlier commits, red temporarily".  This keeps them from being selected by the rest of the names or IDs we supply.  Then, when we say `v2`, we are asking Git to "paint commit v2, and earlier unpainted commits, green temporarily."  This paints `D`, `C`, `B`, and `A`, but stops after that as `v1` is painted red.

Adding `origin/master` tells Git to paint commit `K` green, and work backwards.  Commit `J` is a *merge* commit, so Git paints `J` green and then begins painting *both* parents, `D` and `I`.  Eventually it works its way back to the already-red `v1` so it stops there.

Finally, Git looks at all the green-painted commits.  That's all of `A` through `K` plus `v2`.

If we leave out `v2`—if we ask for

```
git log ^v1 origin/master
```

for instance—we will no longer see commit `v2` itself, as it was never painted green temporarily; but we will still see all of `A` through `K`.

Note that this—the `^v1 origin/master` form—is equivalent to `v1..origin/master`.  I think you are writing `origin/master v1..` or `v1.. origin/master` (note the space after the `..`!); in this case, the "missing" name is filled in with `HEAD`, which names your current commit.  So these other commands use `^v1 HEAD origin/master` as the red-paint and green-paint names.

Aside: all the "red paint" (hat-prefixed) operations are done first; or equivalently, you can think of this as "paint red over green, but never paint green over red" and do them in either order.  (And remember, all the paint washes off again, right after the Git command finishes. :-) )